# Dimensions of SO8W package footprint

Tags: pcb, packages, footprint

I'm looking for the pad dimensions and land patterns for the `SO8W` package. [This page](http://www.luciani.org/geda/pcb/footprints-gif/SO-gif.html) has drawings of many `SO` footprints, but no dimensions.

Where can I find dimensions for the `SO8W` package's PCB footprint?

Comment: [Useful source](http://www.linear.com/designtools/packaging/index.php) for IC packaging information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SO8W (Wide) package dimensions are as follows:

[image: SO8W footprint]

For confirmation, the datasheet of the specific part would be of value.

For land pattern and pad dimensions, just use a SO8N package layout, and split it down the middle to fit the wide package.

For a comprehensive list of package dimensions, see [this link](http://tersted.home.xs4all.nl/PDF_files/CutlerHammer/design.pdf).